# Version control in Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I am going to use a version control system like Github.

My project is an Xcode project and I am not sure which files should be excluded when I commit to the repository.

- Should I commit "Pods" folder?
- Should I commit "xcodeproj" and "xcworkspace"?

Comment: Send everything in your project folder where you have an Xcode project file with the extension of xcodeproj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if there are multiple developers, it's better to avoid xcworkspace file because when there are multiple build version or bundle identifier, it's likely to get a conflict. A conflict in the xcworkspace file won't open any files inside the project until and unless you resolve the conflict. You'll have to use merge tool or some other tools to resolve the conflict. Hence better to avoid xcworkspace file. It's fine to commit the pods folder.

Comment: What kind of tools do you recommend for merging that?

Comment: I use the built in merge tool of XCode. It's not one of the best but does the work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes to xcodeproj, maybe for xcworkspace or Pods.

I recommend you take a look at the Swift.ignore file that Github uses for a thorough checklist of what to include in source control and what to avoid:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Swift.gitignore

From that file, here is what it says about xcworkspace and Pods:

```
# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
# Pods/
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from the Xcode workspace
# *.xcworkspace
```